# How do I console.log the value of a hidden input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am building an application where users can add elements into a list. Each of these elements has a hidden input value which is equal to it's ID in the database.

```
<a>
<p>Name</p>
<p>Start</p>
<p>End</p>
<input type="hidden" value="15">
</a>
```

How do I access the value stored in the hidden input field?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 3):

You would access it the same way you would get the value of a visible field, the hidden property only affects how it is displayed.

`$('.selector').val();`

Answer (score 1):

get value of all inputs with type=hidden

```
$('input[type=hidden]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
$('a input[type=hidden]').val();
```